# .htaccess is not redirecting certain URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So I have been dabbling with .htaccess and URL rewriting recently and it has been working well until recently.
Basically I redirect all URL's to index.php which then processes the URL and displays the right content. so if I enter `http://www.example.com/blog/index.html` that works and displays properly. But if I enter `http://example.com/blog/` I get a 404 error... Below I have put both the .htaccess code and the PHP code just in case.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
```

and the PHP:

```
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.html'))
    {
        //Looks like we are accessing the root
        $this->controller = $this->config['default'];
    } else {
        $this->uri = explode('/', str_replace('.html', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        $this->controller = $this->uri[1];

        if(isset($this->uri[2]))
        {
            $this->action = $this->uri[2];
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is a **404 error** from server or PHP?

Comment: sorry, it is generated by Apache

Comment: Looks like you call 2 different files, `http://www.example.com/blog/index.html` and `index.php` in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .htaccess should look like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: I added the \.html bit just so then i can have .html added onto the URL

Comment: Well then `http://example.com/blog/` would use Apache default routing and bypass your rewrites entirely. If you get a 404, that likely means that an index file isn't physically present in `/blog` and `Indexes` are disabled.

Comment: What you want to do sounds like a nice feature, but same content with 3 different URL is not very useful for good ranking.